# "I am a citizen of Britain" vs. "I am a subject of the British crown" vs. "I am a British national"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases

Which phrase is the most common for a person who was born in Britain of the parents who were also born in Britain to identify his nationality?

1. "I am a citizen of Britain"?
2. "I am a subject of the British crown"?
3. "I am a British national"?

And is there a better alternative?

Comment: The difference between British national and British citizen is a legal one, not a linguistic one. See for example https://www.gov.uk/types-of-british-nationality

Comment: Ordinary UK citizens have not been 'subjects' since 1983.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first of your suggestions is best, but I would like to suggest a better alternative:

> I am a British citizen

Comment: Agreed, that's the usual option in multiple choice questions about nationality in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

We need to be careful here. It may be better to ask this question on the Law site.

There are actually six forms of British nationality - with different names. And the mere fact that a person is born in Britain, even if both parents were born in Britain does not necessarily, I feel sure, make them British, under any of the six categories.

[This British government website tells you about the six categories, and what they are called.](https://www.gov.uk/types-of-british-nationality/british-citizenship)

**However if it is simply a linguistic question - a person born in Britain of parents who were British citizens is "a British citizen". At least that's the form of words used in my passport.**

Comment: There's also "British Citizen" and "British Citizen by Descent" which are absolutely not the same thing legally. Getting this wrong may have fatal legal consequences for your kids.

Comment: Note that the question asks "of parents who were born in Britain". Not the same thing.

Comment: @gnasher729 The Government site to which I provided a link mentions six categories of nationality. There is no mention of anything called "British citizen by descent" and I have never heard of any such-named category.